# How can I create a win and loss dictionary that keeps track of the amount of rolls it takes to win or loose a game?

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics, append, 2d-games

I am new to coding in python. This is a craps game. It is played 50 times and I am able to output the wins and losses, I am also able to keep track of the rollcount. I want to make a dictionary that keeps track of the number of rolls it takes to win a game and loose a game(one win and one loose dictionary). For example this would be the key and value for an item. 4 : 20 meaning that it took four rolls to win or loose (depending if it was a win dictionary or a loss dictionary)when the game was played fifty times.
This is what I have so far. I'm eager to learn but I am stuck here. I would appreciate any help.

```
import random


from collections import Counter

def roll_dice():
    """Roll two dice and return their face values as a tuple."""
    die1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    die2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    return (die1, die2)  # pack die face values into a tuple

def display_dice(dice):
    """Display one roll of the two dice."""
    die1, die2 = dice  # unpack the tuple into variables die1 and die2
    print(f'Player rolled {die1} + {die2} = {sum(dice)}')
def clear_values():
    """Clear rollcount  """


gamecount = 0
wincount = 0
losecount = 0
rollcount = 0
list_of_win = {}
list_of_loss = {}
win_roll = {1:0, 2 : 0, 3 : 0, 4 : 0, 5 : 0, 6 : 0, 7 : 0, 8 : 0, 9 : 0, 10 : 0, 11 : 0, 12 : 0, 13 : 0, 14 : 0, 15 : 0, 16 : 0, 17 : 0, 18 : 0, 19 : 0}
lose_roll = {1:0, 2 : 0, 3 : 0, 4 : 0, 5 : 0, 6 : 0, 7 : 0, 8 : 0, 9 : 0, 10 : 0, 11 : 0, 12 : 0, 13 : 0, 14 : 0, 15 : 0, 16 : 0, 17 : 0, 18 : 0, 19 : 0} 

while gamecount != 50:
    rollcount = 0
    die_values = roll_dice()
    rollcount += 1  # first roll
    display_dice(die_values)

# determine game status and point, based on first roll
    sum_of_dice = sum(die_values)

    if sum_of_dice in (7, 11):  # win
        wincount += 1
        gamecount += 1
        list_of_win = [{rollcount : key, "nbr": value} for key, value in Counter(list_of_win).values()]
        game_status = 'WON'
    elif sum_of_dice in (2, 3, 12):  # lose
        losecount += 1
        list_of_loss =[{rollcount : key, "nbr": value} for key, value in Counter(list_of_loss).values()]
        gamecount += 1
        game_status = 'LOST'
    else:  # remember point
        game_status = 'CONTINUE'
        my_point = sum_of_dice
        print('Point is', my_point)

# continue rolling until player wins or loses
    while game_status == 'CONTINUE':
        die_values = roll_dice()
        rollcount += 1
        display_dice(die_values)
        sum_of_dice = sum(die_values)

        if sum_of_dice == my_point:  # win by making point
            game_status = 'WON'
            wincount += 1
            list_of_win =[{rollcount : key, "nbr": value} for key, value in Counter(list_of_win).values()]
            gamecount += 1
        elif sum_of_dice == 7:  # lose by rolling 7
            game_status = 'LOST'
            losecount += 1
            list_of_loss =[{rollcount : key, "nbr": value} for key, value in Counter(list_of_loss).values()]
            gamecount += 1

# display "wins" or "loses" message

    if game_status == 'WON':
        print('Player wins')

    else:
        print('Player loses')

print(f'| {wincount} = wins |\n| {losecount} = losses |\n| {gamecount} = games played |')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but don't need the Counter object.

For the explanation, let's just take keeping track of wins. You'll be able to track losses similarly.

Instead of the places you assign list_of_wins, you can just increment the counter stored in win_rolls.  You've already initialized the value for that rollcount in the dictionary to 0, so we can just add 1.

```
win_roll[rollcount] += 1
```

You'll have to do this in the two places, where you assign list_of_win.

Then at the end of the program you can print out all the keys and values in the dictionary.

```
for key, value in win_roll.items():
    print(f'{key} : {value}')
```

Of course, it's possible that it could take more than 19 rolls to win a game, in which case this code won't work. Take the example of it taking 30 rolls to win or lose (unlikely but still statistically possible). Since you haven't initialized an entry in the dictionary for the key of 30, there won't be a value there to increment.

In this case we can check for the existence of the key in the dictionary and act appropriately. Instead of

```
win_roll[rollcount] += 1
```

We use

```
if rollcount in win_roll:
    win_roll[rollcount] += 1
else:
    win_roll[rollcount] = 1
```

You can do the same for loss_roll to track the number of times each rollcount won or lost.